# Remover string "dist" de build com Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

criei uma `rule` no meu arquivi `webpack.config.js` para poder trabalhar com fontes dentro do meu `scss`, porém quando faço o `build` para produção a `string` para carregar o arquivo fica como:

```
/distfonts/minha_font.woff
```

Sendo que a pasta é apenas `fonts/minha_font.woff`

Regra usada no `webpack`:

```
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
},
```

A saída atual é:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: hk_groteskmedium;
    src: url(/distfonts/hkgrotesk-medium-webfont.woff2) 
    format("woff2"),url(/distfonts/hkgrotesk-medium-webfont.woff) 
    format("woff");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```

A saída correta seria apenas `src: url(fonts/hkgrotesk-medium-webfont.woff2)`

Comment: Faz tempo que não toco em Webpack mas, se você por o caminho como relativo altera algo? `loader: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'`

Comment: se eu colocar `./fonts` o `output` fica `/dist./fonts`

Comment: Bem, acho que minha última sugestão seria tentar o argumento outputPaths. `'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'&outputPath=fonts/`. Tem um exemplo legal neste link: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: já tentei, da mesma maneira continua colocando essa string `dist` no inicio